# Relationship between modular form at transformed input and original form

Tags: modular-forms

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to find some way to relate some $\Gamma_0(2)$ leveled modular form $f(\tau)$ to a transformed version of it at $f(-\dfrac{1}{2\tau})$. So far, I've found that there ought to be a relationship between the two for fully modular forms where $ f(-\dfrac{1}{2\tau}) = f(\dfrac{1}{2}\tau)$ (conjectured but not proven). However, for $\Gamma_0(2)$ forms that are not properly modular, I have not been able to find a general relationship. Is there a source that describes how to relate these two?

To be specific about what type of relationship I'd like, it should be one that readily allows one to compare $q$-expansions (i.e. $f(-\dfrac{1}{2\tau}) = f(\dfrac{1}{2}\tau)$ implies, for $\hat{f}(\tau) = f(-\dfrac{1}{2\tau})$, that $\hat{f}(q) = f(\sqrt{q})$).

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide!

Comment: Try Googling for "Atkin-Lehner involution".

Comment: That’s perfect for what I needed, thank you David!